# OpenSSH : Putty won't work with Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: server, 16.04, openssh, putty

We use Putty to access our Linux servers from our windows workstations...

Today we created new servers with **Ubuntu server 16.04** and installed openssh with tasksel (as allways).

When we try to connect remotely to our new **Ubuntu server 16.04**, we get a PuTTY Fatal Error...

```
Couldn't agree a client-to-server cipher (available: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com)
```

[image: PuTTY Fatal Error]

Please tell me how to work around this problem !
Someone found a solution?

Comment: What version of putty are you using?

Comment: As above - there's a chance you're using oldish version of Putty, which can't negotiate proper/newer ciphers. Download latest version of Putty and retry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had the same issue.  Just upgrade Putty.

Comment: This might be indeed working, but it would be helpful if you could tell us to which version you've upgraded putty.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade PuTTY: currently latest release (0.70), visit this [link](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)!